# How do I generate random Strings for a multiple choice game

Tags: android, random

I am building a game that has a question with 4 multiple choice answers (in android studio). I am going to generate three wrong answers and 1 correct answer for all 45 questions in my app. I have a separate method that generates the question randomly (45 different questions). I am not quite sure how to do this.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button startGame;
    TextView questionTextView;
    questions question = new questions();
    ArrayList<String> answers; //gets the correct
    int correctAnswer;

    public void START (View view) {

        startGame.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Random rand = new Random();
        startGame = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);
        questionTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.questionTextview);
        questionTextView.setText(question.getQuestion());


        correctAnswer = rand.nextInt(4);

        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++ ) {

            if(i == correctAnswer) {


            } else {


            }
        }
    }
}






public class questions {

    public String [] mquestions = {


            "Who is the 1st president of the United States?",
            "Who is the 2nd president of the United States?",
            "Who is the 3rd president of the United States?",
            "Who is the 4th president of the United States?",
            "Who is the 5th president of the United States?",
            "Who is the 6th president of the United States?",
            "Who is the 7th president of the United States?",
            "Who is the 8th president of the United States?",
            "Who is the 9th president of the United States?",
            "Who is the 10th president of the United States?",
            "Who is the 11th president of the United States?",
            "Who is the 12th president of the United States?",
            "Who is the 13th president of the United States?",
            "Who is the 14th president of the United States?",
            "Who is the 15th president of the United States?",
            "Who is the 16th president of the United States?",
            "Who is the 17th president of the United States?",
            "Who is the 18th president of the United States?",
            "Who is the 19th president of the United States?",
            "Who is the 20th president of the United States?",
            "Who is the 21st president of the United States?",
            "Who is the 22nd president of the United States?",
            "Who is the 23rd president of the United States?",
            "Who is the 24th president of the United States?",
            "Who is the 25th president of the United States?",
            "Who is the 26th president of the United States?",
            "Who is the 27th president of the United States?",
            "Who is the 28th president of the United States?",
            "Who is the 29th president of the United States?",
            "Who is the 30th president of the United States?",
            "Who is the 31st president of the United States?",
            "Who is the 32nd president of the United States?",
            "Who is the 33rd president of the United States?",
            "Who is the 34th president of the United States?",
            "Who is the 35th president of the United States?",
            "Who is the 36th president of the United States?",
            "Who is the 37th president of the United States?",
            "Who is the 38th president of the United States?",
            "Who is the 39th president of the United States?",
            "Who is the 40th president of the United States?",
            "Who is the 41st president of the United States?",
            "Who is the 42nd president of the United States?",
            "Who is the 43rd president of the United States?",
            "Who is the 44th president of the United States?",
            "Who is the 45th president of the United States?",

    };


    public String getQuestion() {

        String question = "";

        Random rand = new Random();
        //This randomizes the questions!!
        int randomNumber = rand.nextInt(mquestions.length);

        question = mquestions[randomNumber];

        return question;

    }


}
```

Comment: Since the possible answers need to be credible. You can't really just have a random string. The best aproach would probably be to pick some random words/names from a word bank. It's the same idea as how you pick your question.

Comment: Are you wanting random-random (ie George Taft) or are you wanting to use a name bank with one being valid (who is 44th: Obama, Trump, Bush, Clinton)?

Comment: Use a database. Relate the questions and the answers through an id and mark the correct one with an integer. The wrong ones can be a variable number, so to confuse the things a bit. Use `... ORDER BY RANDOM` to pick the answers unsorted.

Comment: If random-random, I'd create 2 string arrays (firstName/lastName) and populate firstName with all presidents first names and anything else you want to add and similarly lastName. Populate a string list in the same manner that you did the questions, but grab 2 randoms (first name and last name) 3x. I'd update questions to be an object Question with string Question, int firstNameIndex, int lastNameIndex of the right answer. The correct answer being firstName[firstNameIndex] lastName[lastNameIndex] and it should be inserted randomly into the list.

Comment: I guess the OP just wants to grab a random question from a table. And all the possible answers to it from another table, in a shuffled order. Or, at least, that would make sense for me.

Comment: yeah, I wouldn't want to go random-random, personally, but at the same time the question alludes to that possibility so I tried to include info to that end. Then again, George Jefferson would be an interesting president.

Comment: I'd vote for John Fitzgerald Carter. ;)

Comment: ... or Barack Clinton.

Comment: ...or HillaryTrump. But yeah, OP should give a bit more details to the question as it's not really possible to answer at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

The best way in my opinion is have a class for your questions. Have a class for your answers. In your question class, create setters and getters as well as a constructor to add the question to a list.

In your answer class, have setters and getter for 3 wrong answers and one for the correct answer. In your contructor, have it take in 4 answers, one of which is the correct answer. You can set it up so the first String in the constructor is always the right answer. From there, add that into into a list.

You will have two lists.
One with questions.
One with answers.

Choose a number at random.
If that number is 1, GET the question at position 1 in the question list and get the answers at position 1 as well. Since you know the CORRECT answer is in the first position of the constructor, you can GET that answer from the list using the answer.getCorrectAnswer() or whatever.

Hopefully this makes sense. It should be able to get worked out from there.

Answer (score 0):

What sort of answer are you looking for?  If the questions are arithmetic, then you can generate random numbers for the wrong answers (checking for a duplicate of the right answer).  If the answers are years: "What year did ..." then generate a year in a reasonable range, again checking that it does not match the correct answer.

If the answers are more complex, then it is probably best to include the wrong answers with your right answers.  The `Question` class will contain four strings: `rightAnswer` and an array of three wrong answers: `wrongAnswer[0] ... wrongAnswer[2]`.  Your question bank is an array of `Question` and each question will contain its right answer and three wrong answers.

If the questions are similar, "Which President ..." then you can use the right answer from one question as a wrong answer for different, but similar, questions.

Answer (score 0):

I built a multiple choice game. Firstly you should create an array how many question do you have. Then create a random and use shuffling. 
Like that.

```
    int array[]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20}; //how many question do you have 

    for (shuffle = array.length - 1; shuffle > 0; shuffle--) {
         randomNumber = rnd.nextInt(20);
         int temp = array[randomNumber];
         array[randomNumber] = array[shuffle];
         array[shuffle] = temp;
    }
```

I think you should use two dimensional arrays. For example 
`array[0][0] = "question"` and other indexes are like that`array[0][1] = "answer1", array[0][2] = "answer2"`

and after shuffling you can put it in array[][].